# Angular Material: Change Background color of tabs when clicked/active

Tags: angular-material

I want to remove the background-color effect applying when clicked on tab in angular material:

Here is the link of [md-tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)

When I click on the tab, I can see a background-color is applying to the div element:

Here is the [screenshot](http://snag.gy/gkGHF.jpg)

I tried to over-ride the style with the following code, but not taking into effect:

```
.md-ripple-container:active{
    background-color: none; !important
}
```

Help!!

Comment: If you post some code it would be better for us to help you back.

Comment: @KevinAndrid- Okay. I will create one fiddle

Comment: @KevinAndrid- Here is the JSFiddle file -https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/87/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `.md-tab.md-active` class in `css`. see the below example.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/JXbVQN

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I tried the your solution, but it is not removing the pink background-color effect. I have created one jsfiddle file. Please check.https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/87/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. :-).. Accepting your answer

Comment: No problem at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override material styling from your scss/css. Like this:

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-group.mat-primary mat-tab-label-active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Due to view encapsulation, you need to use **/deep/** selector that will allow you to get hold of the Material class added when the component is rendered.