# Override background color in active tabs Angular Material

Tags: css, angular-material

I'm triyng to override the background color of the active tabs in Angular Material. I've tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027954/angular-material-change-background-color-of-tabs-when-clicked-active) but with no success. Inspecting chrome I see these values:

```
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:focus, .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:focus {
    background-color: rgba(241, 204, 206, 0.3);
}
```

Unchecking, I get the desired effect, but if I paste it into my style sheet, nothing happens. Any ideas?

EDIT: the full CSS

```
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:focus, .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:focus, .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:focus {
    background-color: rgba(241, 204, 206, 0.3);
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-label:focus {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-label:focus {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-label {
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: .6;
    min-width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-label {
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: .6;
    min-width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-label, .mat-tab-link {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-ripple {
    overflow: hidden;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-label, .mat-tab-link {
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
user agent stylesheet
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
Inherited from mat-tab-group.mat-tab-group.mat-primary.mat-background-black
<style>…</style>
.mat-tab-group {
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
Inherited from mat-card.login-card.mat-card
<style>…</style>
.mat-card {
    background: white;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-card {
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this CSS, it works on inspect element:

```
md-tabs .md-tab.md-active {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

EDIT:
For Angular 2+ Material:

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Err... You're referencing AngularJS Material, while the OP wants Angular Material 2/5.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding more specificity to your selectors.

For example:

```
body .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:focus, body .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:focus, body .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label:focus, body .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link:focus {
    background-color: rgba(241, 204, 206, 0.3);
}
```

Note that this is just for tabs with focus, for initial state use this:

```
body .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-label, body .mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-tab-link, body .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-label, body .mat-tab-nav-bar.mat-primary .mat-tab-link {
    background-color: rgba(241, 204, 206, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Alex, but it's not working, I've tried both (with !important)

Comment: Don't use !important, could you copy all the css from dev tools?

Comment: Doesn't look like your CSS is being loaded in otherwise there would be more than one reference with the above property declaration. Can you check you have the path written correctly and that there are no errors in the console regarding the stylesheet?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but no, I dont see any errors...And other implemented classes work...

Comment: Is there any issue with your CSS then perhaps? Maybe a typo is blocking out part of the stylesheet. Try adding in some test styles below your declaration. If you have put the above code into your stylesheet and it's not showing up in dev tools then seems like an error with the CSS.